Flutter GoogleMaps conflict with Cocoapods
I have runed pod install in vs code terminal but I'm receiving this error :
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
In Podfile:
google_maps_flutter_ios (from .symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter_ios/ios) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
GoogleMaps (< 9.0, >= 8.4)
Specs satisfying the GoogleMaps (< 9.0, >= 8.4) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
Please can anyone help me ?
I have runed pod install in vs code terminal but I'm receiving this error :

Open Podfile and set the iOS version to 14.0
, because this line did the trick :)

Then go to the main project folder and run the below lines into terminal:
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update

Happy Coding!

It helped thanks, I set it to 14.0

Welcome to stackoverflow. This comment was written as part of a review task. Posting comments as an answer is not encouraged on stackoverflow and this anwer will most likely be deleted. Instead, upvote the answer or comment that you find helpful. This will increase the reputation rating of the user who helped you. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

You can do following.
1.delete podfile.lock and in your iOS directory run pod install --repo-update
2.if it does not help find # platform :ios, '12.0' this line in your Podfile and uncomment it , set it to 13.0 and do 1 step

1 - Step:
- Run
rm Podfile.lock

2 - Step:
# add this in the first line of the podfile
$iOSVersion = '15.0'

platform :ios, $iOSVersion
pod 'GoogleMaps', '9.0.0'

3 - Step
Add:
  # Override Firebase SDK Version
  $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.22.0'

In:
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Override Firebase SDK Version
  $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.22.0'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

4 - Step
- Run
pod install --repo-update

5 - Step
have peace again


Run flutter clean,
Open the ios folder in your flutter app,
Delete the pods folder,
Delete the Podfile.lock file,
Run flutter pub get,
Run cd ios,
Open Podfile file and uncomment # platform :ios, '12.0' and change '12.0' to '14.0'.
Finally run pod install --repo-update.

I hope this helps

I followed these exact steps, but I'm still getting:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
In Podfile:
GoogleMaps (= 7.1.0)
google_maps_flutter_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter_ios/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
  GoogleMaps (< 10.0, >= 8.4)

Specs satisfying the GoogleMaps (= 7.1.0), GoogleMaps (< 10.0, >= 8.4) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
Just updated to Flutter 3.22, pubspec.yaml update to latest google maps versions.

I was having the same issue, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.   After some digging, I discovered that a new version of the Maps SDK for IOS was released at the end of May 2024, version 9.0.0: Google Maps iOS SDK Release Notice
The release information also suggests updating the iOS target to 15.0. With this information, I updated my podfile to reference ios 15.0 and GoogleMaps pod 9.0.0:
platform :ios, '15.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '9.0.0'

then ran:
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update

and got a clean build.
One other useful resource (and what pointed me to the above release notes) is the Google Maps presence on the CocoaPods web site: Google Maps changelog on cocoapods.org Might be a good idea to bookmark that!
